# Simple file share web application

Tags: linux, self-hosted, uploader, file-server

For my graduation I have to deliver documents to my examiners on a regular bases. There is a solution provided by the school to do this, but is really painful to use. So I am looking for an alternative web application.

I have a VPS to host the application on. It can be PHP+MySQL or Java or whatever (it has to run on Linux though).

It has to have a nice looking front-end. I already looked at WordPress which is okay-ish, but the focus of the portfolio templates there is mainly on visual designers and creativity. The documents I have to deliver are boring PDF files with charts and stuff.

So the requirements:

- Has to run on Linux server
- Be able to upload files to it
- Has to have a reasonable nice file list interface
- Nice to have: Versioning of files

Comment: There are a lot of applications (with different requirements, too), have a look at this list:
https://github.com/Kickball/awesome-selfhosted#single-clickdrag-n-drop-upload

Comment: i'm not sure if it is what you are looking for and may be a little bit of a overshot, but maybe worth a look: [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) with it's [sharing capabilities](https://nextcloud.com/sharing/) and versioning for sure...

Comment: Before you even start  - are ***all*** of your examiners agreeable to using a "non-school approved" solution (which they have to learn to use)? I would very much doubt it.

Comment: @JacksGT Thanks! this is very useful list!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy I think this is a bit too much, thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @Mawg thanks for thinking with me! And I agree this is the fact in most cases. But the system we "must" use according to the regulations is a crappy system. The examiners prefer to receive it in e-mail.

Comment: "`The examiners prefer to receive it in e-mail`", so I ask you again if you have discussed it with them & if they are willing to learn a new file sharing system - all of them, plus any you might have next year? A ***serious*** suggestion is that, if the current system is really so crappy, you offer to develop a new one (if you have coding skills). Either for money (less likely), or for course credits – as an alignment.

Answer (score 1):

[NemakiWare](http://nemakiware.com) does that, and file versioning too.

1. Install it on your server (Linux/Mac/Windows).
2. Log in as admin, you have a "file explorer"-like interface to upload the documents.
3. Create user accounts.
4. Set the permission correctly, so that each user can see what is relevant to them.
5. Send the URL/username/passwords to your users.

Free, open source.
Disclaimer: Made by my company.

[image: NemakiWare web client]